# Как сменить цвет SVG при наведении курсора?

Tags: jquery, css, svg

[image: Пример]
Cвойства:

1. SVG иконка будет ссылкой (только область svg будет кликабельной, а не весь блок в котором находится иконка).
2. Смена цвета при наведении курсора.
3. Возможность корректировки положения внутри блока.

На просторах интернета прочитал множество статей, возможно есть более удачные и корректные практики на ваш взгляд. Поделитесь, пожалуйста, опытом.
К примеру если встроить SVG в html документ, то он не будет кэшироваться, что не очень хорошо, если будет несколько SVG.

Какой оптимальный вариант на Ваш взгляд?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

из своего опыта могу предложить два варианта:

1. Если много svg иконок, собрать все в один шрифт, потом использовать эти шрифты где нужно через font-family: <название шрифта>, а нужный шрифт через content: 'id символа/иконки'. А дальше вешаешь в css :hover и меняешь color для шрифта, оч удобно.
2. Как ты писал, вставлять в html svg, и так же на css можешь менять через :hover, но только там у тебя будет свойство не color, а fill

если я ничего не упустил, то тут jquery тебе вообще не нужен

Comment: Дополните, пожалуйста, ответ мини инструкцией добавления иконок в шрифт или ссылкой на метод, который используете.

Comment: есть куча сервисов с готовыми иконками, которые можно собрать в один шрифт + добавить свои, есть также аля фреймворки. Вот к примеру сервисы с набором + добавлением своих: `https://glyphter.com`, `http://flaticon.com`. И готовый набор: `http://fontawesome.io`

Comment: вот вроде не плох ещё: `http://fontello.com`